# Problem after installing snapd

Tags: linux, fedora, snap

I'm running fedora 32 workstation, and I installed `snapd`. When I try to install snap software it shows

```
Too early for this operation, device not yet seeded or device model not yet acknowledged
```

What to do to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these commands.... This helps

"snap wait system sees.loaded"
And
"systemctl restart snapd.seeded.service"

Enter these without quotes.